# Why can't I see my pictures in the folder its suppose to be in?

Tags: animation

In the Video editing mode of Blender, I can't see the pictures imported from my camera in my folder. But when I am in file explorer, they're rightfully there!!!

Comment: Files displayed in Blender file manager window depend on the mode you are in. How are you opening this file manager?

Answer (score 1):

You might have a filter in the file browser selected.

[image: file browser filters]